# Cache/Log permissions in Symfony2 on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: linux, caching, symfony, permissions, amazon-web-services

I've set up Symfony2 on the AWS Linux AMI (a free tier micro instance) and set up PHP-FPM and nginx successfully.

My Symfony app works.. until I use the command line to clear the cache. When I do this the `/app/logs` and `app/cache/` folder becomes owned by `root` and the app can no longer write to it.

I can manually `chmod 777` / `chown nginx:nginx` these files after each cache clear, but there must be a better way?

I've tried using a bash function to `su nginx;` before it clears the cache, but that doesn't work.

Before cache folder before cache clear:

```
drwxrwxrwx 11 nginx nginx 4096 Nov  4 13:23 dev
drwxrwxrwx 10 nginx nginx 4096 Nov  4 20:39 prod
```

And after:

```
drwxrwxrwx 11 nginx nginx 4096 Nov  4 13:23 dev
drwxr-xr-x 10 root  root  4096 Nov  4 20:39 prod
```

Is this something I can fix in the app, or is there a way of setting up the permissions so they don't become `root`ed?

Edit: I should also mention I tried:

```
sudo chmod +a "nginx allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
```

But the server doesn't recognise `+a`.

Also tried using:

```
 setfacl -R -m u:nginx:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

Which doesn't error, but doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**
Can't accept this answer yet but this worked for me:
So I successfully enabled ACL on my mount following the guide here: http://blog.dsyph3r.com/2011/09/symfony2-using-setfacl-for-cache-and.html

For newbies like, me note the label of the drive is (somewhat strangely) `"Label=/"` in `fstab`.

Once that was done I used

```
 setfacl -R -m u:nginx:rwx app/cache app/logs
 setfacl -dR -m u:nginx:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

Now I can clear cache at will it seems.

**Original (only use if you cannot or will not enabled ACL):**
I followed a help page which got me to set `umask(0000);` in numerous places, namely the `app/app*.php`s and the `app/console` script. This seems to have worked, but I'm not sure of the implications.

Leaving question open for non-umask solutions. Looking into activating ACL on my mount, but new to that and it all seems.. strangely named.

Answer (score 0):

sudo -u nginx php app/console cache:clear

Comment: Is this not the same as running a bash function with `su nginx;` at the top? I'll try now anyway as I prefer it to changing files to suit environment.

Comment: Have in mind  that for the prod environment you should add --env=prod and probably --no-debug

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to work. It doesn't even create the cache files with that. (I can't `su nginx` either, it says "the user is not available")

Comment: To be honest the command I gave you works in Centos. I am not familiar with AMI. Sorry.

Comment: No worries mate, I think there's something odd with my nginx user (I don't want to go near it, lest I anger it)